# Calling a sql file via exec() in php from a different directory?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have a PHP script which downloads two huge sql files (about 200MB each). The first one does a bunch of stuff, then it calls the second one. From the command line, I can type these two lines and it works fine:

```
> cd /path/to/the/sql/files
> mysql -uroot -ppassword < firstfile.sql
```

But when I have PHP try to do exec() the first file, it fails to launch the second file, presumably because PHP is operating in a different directory. I tried to do this, which is probably really naive:

```
exec("cd /path/to/the/sql/files");
exec("mysql -uroot -ppassword < firstfile.sql");
```

Is there a way to get that second exec() to know what directory to run from?

Comment: Any reason you can't just have `... < /path/to/the/sql/files/firstfile.sql`?

Answer (score 1):

The environment modified in the process which is forked to exec your cd command is lost when that process exits, and so does not effect the execution of the second command.

If you cannot make it work by giving full paths to the data files, you can make it work by executing both the cd command and the mysql command in the same exec(), separating them with a semicolon.

```
exec("cd /path/to/the/sql/files; mysql -uroot -ppassword < firstfile.sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the full path at the start of the line:

`exec("/path/to/mysql -uroot -ppassword < firstfile.sql");`